# Let's assume that I get number as string or hex or int and I want to convert to integer. I'm looking for a more generic form

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume that I get number as string or hex or int and I want to convert to integer. I'm looking for a more generic form.

for example,
if I write:
int('0x10',16) then int('0x10') will throw exception.

if I write:
int('10') then int('10',16) will throw exception.

Do I need to check type with instanceof ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. And `int('10',16)` doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: When you cast string to a int, you need to know the base which you are casting to.. you can't just assume it's decimal as long as there isn't any '0x' in it.

Comment: Can you specify your object or clarify on what do you mean by ‘more generic form’....

Answer (score 0):

If the string represents a valid hex, it is prefixed by `0x`. So, you could just check `value.startswith('0x')`

Comment: what if he tries `int('1D')`, the OP question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the base ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)), when using int() on a hex value:

```
>>> _hex = hex(int("32"))
>>> _hex
'0x20'
>>> int(_hex, 0)  # 0 means: Python automatically detects hex or decimal
32
```